# SAP HANA | With Clause performance

Tags: hana

We are using SAP HANA 1.0 SPS12.

We have daywise table like below -

```sql
select trans_date,article,measure1,measure2 from table_1
```

Volume of table ~ 5 millions rows

we need to see data like -

```sql
select 'day-1',sum(measure1),sum(meaure2) from table1 where trans_date=add_days(current_date,-1) group by 'day-1'
union all
select 'day-2',sum(measure1),sum(meaure2) from table1 where trans_date>=add_days(current_date,-2) group by 'day-2' 
union all
select 'WTD',sum(measure1),sum(meaure2) from table1 where trans_date>=add_days(current_date,-7) group by 'WTD'
union all
select 'WTD-1',sum(measure1),sum(meaure2) from table1 where trans_date>=add_days(current_date,-15) and trans_Date <= add_days(current_date,-7) group by 'WTD-1'
```

so on and so forth for MTD,MTD-1,MTD-2,YTD.

Performance wise is it better to use WITH CLAUSE and hold data for one year and then split according to timeframe? OR Is it better to use separate aggregation for each timeframe as shown above.

As far as I understand, in RDBMSs like Oracle, WITH CLAUSE materializes results and use it from the memory. SAP HANA is In Memory database itself. Does using WITH CLAUSE in SAP HANA gives distinctive performance edge?

Query using WITH CLAUSE -

```sql
WITH t1 as
(
select trans_date,sum(measure1),sum(meaure2) from table1 where trans_date>=add_days(current_date,-365)
)
select 'day-1',sum(measure1),sum(meaure2) from t1 where trans_date=add_days(current_date,-1) group by 'day-1'
union all
select 'day-2',sum(measure1),sum(meaure2) from t1 where trans_date>=add_days(current_date,-2) group by 'day-2' 
union all
select 'WTD',sum(measure1),sum(meaure2) from t1 where trans_date>=add_days(current_date,-7) group by 'WTD'
union all
select 'WTD-1',sum(measure1),sum(meaure2) from t1 where trans_date>=add_days(current_date,-15) 
                          and trans_Date <= add_days(current_date,-7) 
                          group by 'WTD-1'
```

Comment: The equal-selections do look rather wrong when you like to get ranges of data as the names for the selection groups suggest. YTD: year-to-date, MTD: month-to-date. 
With the point-selections you have in there, you only get the transactions that happened exactly the on the day e.g. one month ago.

Comment: Thanks!...Corrected the same. Any comment on performance of WITH CLAUSE?

Comment: How would you write the query with the WITH clause? Can you add that to the question?

Comment: I have added query with 'WITH CLAUSE'

Comment: For this query, the HANA query optimizer rewrites the statement so that it is equal to the UNION ALL case. The result of the common table expression does not get materialized in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about performance, putting the data in a single row should be much better:

```
select sum(case when trans_date = add_days(current_date, -1) then measure1 end) as measure1_day1,
       sum(case when trans_date = add_days(current_date, -1) then measure2 end) as measure2_day1,
       sum(case when trans_date = add_days(current_date, -2) then measure1 end) as measure1_day2,
       sum(case when trans_date = add_days(current_date, -2) then measure2 end) as measure2_day2,
       . . .       
from table1
where trans_date >= add_days(current_date, -15);
```

You can unpivot the results afterwards, if you really need the values in separate rows.

Alternatively, you can do:

```
select days, sum(measure1), sum(measure2)
from (select 1 as days from dummy union all
      select 2 from dummy union all
      select 7 from dummy union all
      select 15 from dummy
     ) d left join
     table1 t
     on t.trans_date = add_days(current_date, - d.days)
group by days
order by days;
```

Comment: Out of interest: why would putting the data into a single row (via the case clause) be faster?

Comment: @LarsBr. . . . The number of rows in an aggregation has a big effect on performance.  More rows is going to be more expensive than another simple computation.

Comment: Thanks,  @gordon-linoff !
I just tried that out on a test data set on HANA and could not get to the same conclusion. 
As an example. the UNION ALL version took on avg. 15ms
, the SUM(CASE) version 31ms  (2x)
and the statement with the left join 165ms (101x). 

This is not to say, that one way of running this query is always better/worse than the other, but that measuring the alternatives is crucial when performance is important.

Comment: @LarsBr. . . . Try the version with the `where` clause I just added.  This may be faster than the `union all`.